# Decrypt Samsung S2 files?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, encryption

My Samsung S2 just went dead with the encrypted SD Card in it and I found out that KIES didn't backup that memory. The phone was repaired but now I cant read the files on the SD.

Anyone out there who managed to recover encrypted files?

Comment: If you could do that, there wouldn't be much point encrypting it, would there?

Comment: There's no recovering encrypted files.  Sorry.

Comment: To answer Dan, I don't agree: An encryption scheme/algorithm should be public, and let you decrypt it, given you have necessary key(s), even on a different OS.